# What is the industry standard way to store country / state / city in a database of web APP?

Tags: sql, database, nosql, geolocation, iso

For country and state, there are ISO numbers. With City, there is not.

Method 1:

Store in one column:

[Country ISO]-[State ISO]-[City Name]

Method 2:

Store in 3 separate columns.

Also, how to handle city names if there is no unique identifier?

Comment: **DO NOT** concatenate together multiple pieces of info - ***not ever***! Use three separate columns - stringing it together to show on screen is easy, if you need to do that!

Comment: Only cities in the USA?

Comment: Btw, there exists also [IATA](https://www.iata.org/en/services/codes/) codes, but that's more for the travel industry.

Comment: related old SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066825/is-there-an-iso-standard-for-city-identification)

Comment: [Here's some good info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574/7644018) on why storing delimited lists in a DB is a _bad_ idea.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, three separate columns to keep your data. If you want to create a unique identifier, the easiest way would be giving a random 3-10 digit code depending on the size of your data set. However, I would suggest concatenating `[country-code]-[state-code]-[code]` if you have a small data set and if you want human readability to a certain point. `code` can be several things. Here are some ideas:

- of course a random id or even a database row id
- licence plate number/code if there is for a city
- phone area code of the city or the code of the center
- same logic may apply to zip codes
- combination of latitude and longitude of the city center up to certain degree

Here are also more references that can be used:

- [ISO 3166](https://www.iso.org/iso-3166-country-codes.html) is a country codes. In there you can find codes for states or cities depending on the country.
- As mentioned IATA has both Airport and [City codes](https://www.iata.org/en/publications/store/mileage/city-code-directory-ccd/) list but they are hard to obtain.
- [UN Location](https://unece.org/trade/cefact/unlocode-code-list-country-and-territory) list is a good mention but it can be difficult to gather the levels of differentiation, like the airport code or city code or a borough code can be on the same list, but eventually the **UN/LOCODE** must be unique. (Airport codes are used for ICAO, similar to IATA but not the same)
- there are several data sets out there like [OpenTravelData](https://opentraveldata.github.io/opentraveldata/) or [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) that can be used for start but may require digging and converting. They provide unique codes for locations. And many others can be found.

Bonus:
I would suggest checking Schema.org's [City Schema](https://schema.org/City) and other Place Schemas for a conscious setup.